# Выровнять текст по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять текст по вертикали. Высота меняется в зависимости от к-ва букв, слов. 
Очень хорошо бы что бы однострочный текст был на уровне иконки.
На русском языке все в одну строчку и просто замечательно.
Я выровнял только по высоте через `flex`.

```css
.navigation-restaurant {
  background: #e6eaf4;
  padding: 22px 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.display-flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navigation-restaurant .item-1,
.navigation-restaurant .item-10,
.navigation-restaurant .item-11,
.navigation-restaurant .item-12,
.navigation-restaurant .item-2,
.navigation-restaurant .item-3,
.navigation-restaurant .item-4,
.navigation-restaurant .item-5,
.navigation-restaurant .item-7,
.navigation-restaurant .item-8,
.navigation-restaurant .item-9 {
  background-position: 11px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.display-flex>div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu.navigation-restaurant a,
.navigation-restaurant a {
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 10px 0 9px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navigation-restaurant .item-1 {
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNiAoV2luZG93cykiIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6Mjg4MjhGMjJGRjVDMTFFNTlCNTRDMzNDODFBQjJENTciIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6Mjg4MjhGMjNGRjVDMTFFNTlCNTRDMzNDODFBQjJENTciPiA8eG1wTU06RGVyaXZlZEZyb20gc3RSZWY6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDoyODgyOEYyMEZGNUMxMUU1OUI1NEMzM0M4MUFCMkQ1NyIgc3RSZWY6ZG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDoyODgyOEYyMUZGNUMxMUU1OUI1NEMzM0M4MUFCMkQ1NyIvPiA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4gPC9yZGY6UkRGPiA8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4gPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/PmACYb4AAACaSURBVHjaYvj////h/+SDw4wgkoECwILEZiRRL9hiJgYKAbEG+AHxQuzuQAAGJCyAxHYC4p9QNa5I4nBN6AaIAvFNIK4CYnMg/gSVr0CzBKcBukD8ASr2GUp3omnGawAI2wHxV6j4TCBmJNUAEPYB4sVAzIxFDq4POSGRlQ5Y0AUIGPaf3HRAcUIiKi/gdSo+FxyhwAFHAQIMAF5mYMaNa8tNAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-position: 11px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navigation-restaurant a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-position: 7px center !important;
}

.navigation-restaurant .item-1,
.navigation-restaurant .item-10,
.navigation-restaurant .item-11,
.navigation-restaurant .item-12,
.navigation-restaurant .item-2,
.navigation-restaurant .item-3,
.navigation-restaurant .item-4,
.navigation-restaurant .item-5,
.navigation-restaurant .item-7,
.navigation-restaurant .item-8,
.navigation-restaurant .item-9 {
  background-position: 11px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navigation-restaurant a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-position: 7px center!important;
}

.navigation-restaurant a {
  background-color: #799fc3;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0 0 11px;
}

.dropdown-menu.navigation-restaurant a,
.navigation-restaurant a {
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 10px 0 9px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navigation-restaurant .active:hover {
  background-color: #3e516c;
}

.navigation-restaurant .active {
  background-color: #455a78;
}

.navigation-restaurant a:hover {
  background-color: #638fb9;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-restaurant hidden-xs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row display-flex">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <a ui-sref="rest.reservation" ui-sref-active="active" class="item-1" ng-style="{'background-color': $ctrl.countReservations > 0 ? 'red' : ''}" href="/rest/reservation" style="background-color: red;">Reserveerimisteated(1)</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <a ui-sref="rest.delivery-food" ui-sref-active="active" ng-style="{'background-color': $ctrl.countDeliveries > 0 ? 'red' : ''}" class="item-4" href="/rest/delivery-food" style="background-color: red;">Toidu kohaletoimetamine
                        (1)</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <a ui-sref="rest.map" ui-sref-active="active" class="item-10" href="/rest/map">Restoran kaardil</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="">
        <a ui-sref="rest.information" ui-sref-active="active" class="item-1 active" href="/rest/information">Info</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <a ui-sref="rest.menu-delivery" ui-sref-active="active" class="item-11" href="/rest/menu-delivery">Kohaletoimetamise menüü</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <a ui-sref="rest.photo" ui-sref-active="active" class="item-9" href="/rest/photo">Teie Fotod</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <a ui-sref="rest.discount" ui-sref-active="active" class="item-6" href="/rest/discount">Allahindlused ja aktsioonid</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items: center`?

Comment: @diraria не подходит, текст остается на своем месте, а если для родительского блока использовать, то высота не одинаковая будет

Comment: У вас в заголовке "по горизонтали", а в описании "по вертикали".

Comment: @rugabarbo прошу извинения, по `вертикали`

Comment: https://codepen.io/DmitriyShvanyk/pen/Xawgbp

Comment: @soledar10 `Info` по вертикали другое подобное можно выровнять ?

Comment: @jashka - по вертикали в примере выровнено

Comment: @soledar10 да, действительно так, первый раз почему-то не выровнялось. Благодарю. Огромное спасибо.